# Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition for them to be parallel is $\frac {a_1}{a_2} = \frac {b_1}{b_2}= \frac {c_1}{c_2} $

Tags: differential-geometry

Given two planes $a_{i}x + b_{i}y + c_{i}z + d_{i} = 0$,  $i = 1, 2$, prove that a necessary and sufficient condition for them to be parallel is
$\frac {a_1}{a_2} = \frac {b_1}{b_2}= \frac {c_1}{c_2} $,
where the convention is made that if a denominator is zero, the corresponding numerator is also zero (we say that two planes are parallel if they either coincide or do not intersect).

**Note:**
Looking at Do Carmo's book on Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces I found that exercise and I have found it interesting, but I have not been able to prove it.
According to the given definition, for the first implication I have first assumed that $ a_{1}x + b_{1}y + c_{1}z + d_{1} = a_{2}x + b_{2} y + c_{2} z +d_{2} $, from this I obtained that $ a_{1} = a_{2}, b_{1} = b_{2}, c_{1} = c_{2} $ and from this it is immediate that $ \frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} = \frac{c_1}{c_2} $. This is correct?
if this is true, how can I make the other implication? I need some help for this.

Answer (score 1):

Two planes are parallel to each other if the normal vectors are parallel to each other...which implies that the normal vector to one plane is simply a multiple of the normal vector to the other plane parallel to it i.e if $a_1+b_1+c_1=d_1$ is parallel to $a_2+b_2+c_2=d_2$ then $<a_2,b_2,c_2> = k <a_1,b_1,c_1>$ for some k $\in$ R.

Comment: I don't understand how I can conclude the exercise test with what you just mentioned. The result of the exercise is a sufficient and necessary condition, so I don't know what implication I am testing with this. The problem is, I don't know how to apply the definition you wrote. Could you explain this part please.

Comment: for any plane $ax+by+cz=d$ the coefficients $a$,$b$ and $c$ represent the normal to the plane and if two planes are parallel then that would imply that the normal to the planes would also be parallel